# Does a functions __get__ method act like a decorator?

Tags: python, properties, decorator, descriptor

I'm trying to develop an understanding of OOP programming in python and one thing that has confused me is how a function becomes a bound method. What I think I understand so far is

1. In python 3.x "unbound methods" no longer exist. There's only functions and (bound) methods.
2. When an instance invokes a class function `obj.func` descriptor protocol is used and `func.__get__` is invoked
3. The object returned is a bound method to the obj instance where the first parameter (usually self) is the obj being passed

What happens in between step 2 and 3?

It seems like something along the lines of

`obj.func=type(obj).func.__get__(func, obj)`

Where somewhere in `__get__` there's something like a decorator that will then return the bound method.

Comment: A decorator in Python is simply a function that takes one argument of a function and return a function.  The `@decorator` syntax is simply a syntactic sugar that simplifies `func = decorator(func)` subsequent to the `def func(...):` block. Given that `__get__` method takes 2 arguments, that isn't a Python decorator, even though it does return a callable object.

Comment: @metatoaster is still a "wrapper" of some sort? Or does it return a wrapped function?

Comment: The object returned by a call to `func.__get__(...)` can be anything that is an appropriate value for attribute `obj.func`. If a function object or bound method is appropriate here (as the name `func` suggests) it can return that.

Comment: Also of interest is that other sections of that document (e.g. [3.3.2.2](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)), and if you want the implementation on how that is actually done, it would be provided as part of the interpreter (e.g. [CPython's implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/descrobject.c))